# Assistance with a class method in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function I can pass an mysql query into and get the result back or an error, it should also check to see if the user running the code is an admin, if they are then it will get a session variable that holds a number count of the mysql queries ran on the page and then increment it by 1 number and then set it back to a session, also if the user is an admin it will show any error messages.

I know it is not the best code but does it appear like it should work?  Any tips to improve too please.

You can see that I am running another method that gets a session variables value, I then set it to a variable in the current method, I then increment it's value by 1 number and then run the setter method to save it to a session again.  I am not really sure If that is the correct way of doing that?  DO I really need to run all those methods and save them all to a local variable like I am?

Also I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\webserver\htdocs\project2\includes\classes\Database.class.php on line 37

Line 37 is this

```
$this->user_role = $session->get('user_role');
```

Method...

```
public static function query($sql)
{
    global $session; // the $session Object

    //get the session value to see if user is an admin
    $this->user_role = $session->get('user_role');

    //if user is admin, get query counter session value and +1 to it and reset it to a session variable.
    if ($this->user_role >= 9){
        $this->querie_counter = $session->get('querie_counter');
        $this->querie_counter++; // add +1 to the number
        $session->set('querie_counter',$this->querie_counter)
    }

    //run mysql query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        // If admin is viewing then we show the SQL code and the error returned
        if($this->user_role >= 9){
            $error = '<BR><center><font size="+1" face="arial" color="red">An Internal Error has occurred.<BR> The error has been recorded for review</font></center><br>';
            $sql_formatted = highlight_string(stripslashes($sql), true);
            $error .= '<b>The MySQL Syntax Used</b><br>' . $sql_formatted .
            '<br><br><b>The MySQL Error Returned</b><br>' . mysql_error();
        }
        die($error);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: So what is the question? What does not work?

Comment: Well I am looking for any improvemnet,this is the first thing I have wrote for a part of a class,  I am also not sure if the area around where I run another class method to get the user's admin status and query_counter number, I am setting them to a session, just not sure if all the syntax is even correct.

Comment: instead of using a glogal session object, maybe I should create a singlton on my session function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm no one has read the error or?

```
**Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\webserver\htdocs\project2\includes\classes\Database.class.php on line 37**
```

ok you cant use `$this` in a **static** **function** you have to use `self::users`

```
public static function query($sql)
{
    global $session; // the $session Object

    //get the session value to see if user is an admin
    self::user_role = $session->get('user_role');

    //if user is admin, get query counter session value and +1 to it and reset it to a session variable.
    if (self::user_role >= 9){
        self::querie_counter = $session->get('querie_counter');
        self::querie_counter++; // add +1 to the number
        $session->set('querie_counter',$this->querie_counter)
    }

    //run mysql query
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        // If admin is viewing then we show the sql code and the error returned
        if(self::user_role >= 9){
            $error = '<BR><center><font size="+1" face="arial" color="red">An Internal Error has Occured.<BR> The error has been recorded for review</font></center><br>';
            $sql_formatted = highlight_string(stripslashes($sql), true);
            $error .= '<b>The MySQL Syntax Used</b><br>' . $sql_formatted .
            '<br><br><b>The MySQL Error Returned</b><br>' . mysql_error();
        }
        die($error);
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I am cuious, I removed the static from the function part and it still will not seem to allow me to use this instead of self, any ideas why?

Comment: Also for some reason even when using self::user_role self for everything it then gives a parse error where ever self:: is at, I can't put my finger on the problem yet

Answer (score 3):

You can't use $this inside a static method.  Static methods are not tied to any instances of an object, so $this is meaningless inside a static method.

Is user_role a static variable too? If so, you need to use Database::$user_role.

You will also get this error with $this->querie_counter.

Comment: i also wrote that, everyone has forgot to say that using $this in a static function will end in a fatal error,

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be okay, just correct the following points:

- **query** not *querie*
- you should be using `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `stripslashes()`
- `highlight_string()` only highlights PHP code, not SQL - what is it doing there?
- write valid XHTML code in your error message (no `<BR>` nor `<br>` => **`<br />`**)